# how to get number of items checked in checklist in textbox?

Tags: c#, checklistbox

I want to add no items checked in textbox from checklist box. but nothing is showing in textbox.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < chklst_scrips.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            if (chklst_scrips.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                for (int j = 0; ;j++ )

                {

                    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(j);

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: where is your counter? that will increment++++, wrong condition! :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetItemChecked method will be useful in order to find the checked items from the CheckboxList.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
                {
                    string str = (string)checkedListBox1.Items[i];
                    textBox1.Text += str;
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the library for ListItem

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls

Comment: i am not getting that library ...working in windows form application

Comment: suppose if we want to add select checklist box items in listview  in column2

Comment: Hi supa.Please provide clear information when asking questions so this could be useful to answer clearly.Reach me arjunan.developer@gmail.com

Comment: suppose if we want to add select checklist box items in listview in column2

Answer (score 0):

Just create a counter and give it an initial value of 0

```
int counter = 0;
```

And then, increment the counter every time a checkbox is checked, as shown here for example if you have a chechbox called checkBox1:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++
    //Your code here
}
```

You will need to increment the counter in all the checkboxes you have

If you are using a checkedListBox called for example checkedListBox1, you can just use `checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count` and get the number of checked items.